# Systematic ways to design a finite automaton whose input-output function or relation is a given one?

Tags: digital-logic, design, state-machines

Given a function or relation, are there some systematic ways to design a finite automaton whose input-output function or relation is the given function or relation, assuming there is at least one such finite automaton?

If I am not mistaken, this is used a lot for designing Moore or Mealy machines in digital design.

Thanks.

Comment: I am reading some books on formal languages and automata.  I would like to know how to construct a Moore or Mealy machine for a given input output mapping, but can't find it in the books. I don't remember where  I saw that the question is addressed in design of digital circuits.

Comment: I meant what I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I don't understand why you consistently want to change my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookup tables. These make the behavior very obvious.

Use a memory for the lookup behavior. The input is the ADDRESS; the output is the contents of that memory word.

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend some books or things for reading more about it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Encode the states in binary
2. Find the state transitions
3. Make a state machine chart. This will be different for Moore and Mealy machines.